# CakePHP Pagination global configuration

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I am using CakePHP2, and not find how to change (reconfigure) pagination limit, example, from 20 to 30.

There are a "global default limit" to set the number of records into the "paginator" (PaginatorHelper?)?

"global" meaning "all site".

Comment: You’ve not read through the page on the CakePHP docs then? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html

Comment: Yes... "Pagination in CakePHP is offered by a Component in the controller". But as a framework it can be offer another mechanism to "reconfigure" all site, not EACH controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code for CakePHP’s Paginator component, it looks like you can set a global limit in a controller (best place would be your AppController) with the following syntax:

```
...
public $paginate=array(); 
...
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->paginate['limit'] = 15;
}
```

I’ve not tested it, but hope it works as desired.

Comment: Hum... testing at app/Controller/AppController.php, add at beforeFilter() method...   Global error: "Indirect modification of overloaded property ... has no effect".

Comment: if you use the before filter, simply put `public $paginate=array();` in your `AppController`; this error is then resolved. Again, [read the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html). it's all there

Comment: According to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cake-php/Fxh_ldO9noU) $this->paginate['limit'] = 15; and with parent::beforeFilter(); before every controllers' beforeFilter callback

Comment: Ops, OK! THANKS @erem!  Only $this->paginate['limit'] = 15;

Comment: @MartinBean need edit with `public $paginate=array();` and  `$this->paginate['limit'] = 15;` to get my vote/accept. I edited but you not aceept.

Answer (score 3):

In your controller

```
public $paginate = array('limit' => 25);
```

Comment: Yes, this is local, but I need "global", for all site.

Comment: That is what the app controller is for.

Comment: I do test with AppController.php  and OK!   Sorry, my vote was for @Martin. You say nothing, only "your controller"... It is understood as "specific", and I (and any other Cake-beginner) not know that AppController is a "global configuration place".